# DomNodeList length return 0

Tags: php

I'm digging a solution for the last 5 hours and I can't believe that i'm asking my first question here for such a simple problem, so the code is:

```
$urlContents = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'); 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$contents = $dom->loadHTMLFile($urlContents);    //$contents = 'source code from www-google.com'
$divsInDomDoc = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');  // $divsInDomDoc becames a DomNodeList with length = 0
$nNodes = $divsInDomDoc->length  // using this to check length
```

Please somebody help!

Comment: Your code lacks error handling. E.g. file_get_contents() returns false if something went wrong -> `if ( false===$urlContents ) { /* error handling here */ }`. Same with the $dom->loadHTML/loadHTMLFile problem. If that handling had been in place you would have dramatically increased your chances of finding the errors quickly ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip VolkerK, sometimes I rely on debugging too much. I saw the false value with xDebug, even thought I couldn't figure a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Tim Cooper's change, you also need to use `loadHTML()` instead of `loadHTMLFile()`, since you already have the contents of the site in a string. `loadHTMLFile()` is for reading a file.

```
$contents = $dom->loadHTML($urlContents);
```

Comment: THANKS A MILLION. that was it. I'm always trying to read slower and think greater. thanks for showing me how to do ti.